# Tasklet to convert from Spring Batch XML to Java Config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-java-config

Converting a spring boot batch XML to Java Config, Gave a try to change below code to Java Config.

```
<batch:job id="batchJob1">
    <batch:step id="step">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="${throttle.limit}">
            <batch:chunk reader="synchronizedProvisionReader"
                    processor="compositeItemProcessor" writer="subWriter"
                    commit-interval="${commit.interval}"
                             skip-limit="${skip.limit}"
                             retry-limit="${retry.limit}">
                <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessException"/>                           
                </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                <batch:retry-listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="batchRetryListener"/>
                </batch:retry-listeners>
                <batch:streams>
                    <batch:stream ref="fileItemReader" />                           
                </batch:streams>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="dateListener" />                           
                </batch:listeners>

            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="debugStepListener" />
            <batch:listener ref="skipCheckingListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="batchProvisionJobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

My initial attempt got stuck in tasklet, not getting an idea on how to configure tasklet for this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("taskExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Value("${throttle.limit}")
    private int throttleLimit;


    @Bean
    public Job batchProvision(){
        return jobs.get("batchJob1").start(provisionStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("provisionStep").tasklet();
    }             
}
```

Please advice how can i set tasks in Java config as same as in XML

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand where you are exactly facing problem. 
but this is how you can convert your config from XML to java. Hope this helps

```
@Bean
    public ItemProcessor<POJO, POJO> myProcessor1() {
        return new myProcessor1();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<POJO, POJO> myProcessor2() {
        return new myProcessor2();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<POJO, POJO> myProcessor3() {
        return new myProcessor3();
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor<POJO, POJO> mYCompositeItemProcessor() {
        CompositeItemProcessor<POJO, POJO> mYCompositeItemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        List<ItemProcessor<POJO, POJO>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(myProcessor1());
        list.add(myProcessor2());
        list.add(myProcessor3());       
        mYCompositeItemProcessor.setDelegates(list);
        return mYCompositeItemProcessor;
    }



    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs) throws Exception {
        return jobs.get("myJob")
                .start(step1())
                .build()
                .listener(myjobListener)
                .build();

    }
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();     
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }   

  @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").listener(mYCompositeItemProcessor())
                .<POJO, POJO> chunk(50).listener(ChunkListenerbean)
                .reader(temReaderbean).listener(ItemReadListener)
                .processor(mYCompositeItemProcessor()).listener(ItemProcessListener)
                .writer(writerBean).listener(ItemWriteListenerbean).listener(SkipListenerbean).faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class).skipLimit(10)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: How can i set commit-interval="${commit.interval}"

Comment: I think in java config Chunk Size is nothing but commit-interval.